# SQLite: Database connection to a resource-file?

Tags: c#, sqlite

i'm creating a dll which needs to connect to a database file using SQLite.
Unfortunately, since my dll is used as an Excel AddIn, I don't really have a chance to figure out the path of where my dll is (Application references the Excel installation folder, all the Reflection.Assembly stuff is linked to either the Windows\GAC folder or something else). So long story short, I can't just put my SQLite file into my .dll-folder because it won't be found there when just using the connection string with a relative path, e.g. "Data Source=myfile.SQLite", and I can't figure out the full path to my original dll either due to the dll being used as an Excel AddIn.

My idea was to add the SQLite file to my project's resources, but I don't know how I could connect to a project resource with a regular SQLite connection string..is that even possible? If it's not, any other ideas how I could solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should provide some more info: Is the sqlite db containing data that ships with the addin, or is it empty? What is the lifetime/ownership of the data, e.g. can you create a new (empty or from initial template) db at each use, or should the data live longer?

Comment: The database is only used by the addin. It's filled (and queried against) by the addin and needs to be persistent, i.e. an in-memory storage won't be an option.

Answer (score 1):

There a number of less-than-ideal solutions:

1) Open/Create the sqlite db at a location determined by a convention, e.g. C:\Data. This is probably not ideal, but SQLite requires an actual data file, it cannot use e.g. a resource or isolated storage directly (There are other databases that do, see #3).

2) Use isolated storage, and copy the data from isolated storage to a temporary location at startup, and when the application shuts down (or on some other "persist event"), copy the file back to isolated storage.

3) Use a db that supports Isolated Storage, such as VistaDB. The obvious drawcback is the license cost (though small).

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Finally, I managed to get the full path to the workbook using Excel Interop so now I can use the external SQLite file after all!